# Play WTV files on non-media center PC?

Tags: video, windows-8.1, windows-media-center, video-codecs

I have a Home Theater PC (HTPC) running Windows 7 Media Center. I'm using SiliconDust CableCard adapters to record programming like a DVR. Works great!

I'd like to view some of the recorded programs (in WTV format) on my new 8" Dell Venue tablet running Windows 8.1. I can access the files, but when I try to play them it opens up Windows Media Player and I get audio but no video playback. These are not DRM protected files.

I assume this means that Windows 8.1 understands the WTV container format and whatever audio codec is needed is installed but that I don't have the correct video codec installed. Using MediaInfo, it says the WTV video is in MPEG 2 format. (Other video formats like MPEG 4 play fine.)

I installed ffdshow to get an MPEG 2 codec and that allows me to play test MPEG 2 files but doesn't help with the WTV files.

Any thoughts on what I need to install? Thanks!

Comment: Try [Media Player Classic](http://mpc-hc.org/).  Works for me on a WinXP PC.

Comment: That's an option. I suspect installing VLC would work as well (still waiting for their Win8 version from Kickstarter to be released). I'd still rather just use the built-in player if I could figure out what codec I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never did figure out which codec was missing, but the VideoLan VLC player in the Windows Store for apps works great to play the non-copyprotected WTV files.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to convert them to .ts from .wtv with a program like MC-TV Converter.  From there, the program HandBrake should be able to convert them to the necessary format for your tablet!

Comment: Thanks for the thought. I could transcode them. I could also edit out all the commercials and otherwise compress them. But these aren't video's I have any interest in keeping for the long term. It'd just be nice to be able to watch some shows occasionally from my tablet without special preparation. I used to do this with my Win7 notebook no problem. Win8 is missing some codecs though and it doesn't work out of the box. I'm wondering what codec is missing.

Answer (score -1):

install kodi and setup to use wmcserver on your win 7 machine.  then all pcs with kodi can share and set recordings from server.  easy peasy... works on linux, android, mac, ipad/phone/pod... and many other devices.  kodi has codecs and other features

Comment: Make your post more clear.